# Is it pythonic to use generators to write header and body of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, generator, send

If I was to write a file with this content:

```
#You have been defeated!
#It's merely a flesh wound!
We are the knights who say Ni!
We are the knights who say Ni!
We are the knights who say Ni!
```

Would it then be very non-pythonic to do it with a generator using send? I have never seen generators used like this elsewhere.

```
def write(file, header):

    with open(file,'w') as f:
        f.write(header)
        line = (yield)
        while True:
            f.write(line)
            line = (yield)

    return

file='holygrail.txt'
header="#You have been defeated!\n#It's merely a flesh wound!\n"
generator = write(file,header)
generator.send(None)
for i in range(3):
    generator.send('We are the knights who say Ni!\n')
generator.close()
```

I am asking, because the method above would be hugely beneficial to me instead of opening multiple different file streams in a contextlib stack. I would not have to use the contextlib module at all, if I write my files like this.

I have never asked a question like this before, and I don't know, whether it belongs on stackoverflow or not.

Comment: I did not know generators could be used like this! And I don't know why this was down voted.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have a couple of concerns: one, how do you stop the iteration, that is, when does the file get closed? Two, the `generator.send(None)` seems unnecessary if you swap the order of the two lines in the `while True` loop and remove the first `line = (yield)`.

Comment: That's a great idea but read the comment of @chepner carefully.

Comment: @chepner Can I just stop the iteration with generator.close()? I just edited the question and added this. According to the documentation http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send "When send() is called to start the generator, it must be called with None as the argument, because there is no yield expression that could receive the value."

Comment: I think `file` isn't a very fortunate choice for arguments/variables, since it's a [builtin function](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#file).

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I'd say that bit of overhead alone makes this use of a generator unpythonic.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen, since you have working code, I would suggest you ask this kind of question on codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @wnnmaw Thank you! I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com. I'll see if I can transfer the questions.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: actually, `file` *isn't* a built-in function in Python 3, see [here](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html).  So now I'd argue it's often the best name, or at least a decent one.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: even in Python 2, you should use `open` instead of `file` unless in very rare case then you need `isinstance` or a subclass.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like the creativity of your solution, but my subjective opinion would be that using [contextlib.ExitStack()](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) will look cleaner, be more readable, than using the generator since each generator would need to be primed with `generator.send(None)` and explicitly closed.

---

By the way, (even though I think `contextlib` will lead to shorter, more readable code), `write` could be simplified a little bit:

```
def write(file, header):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(header)
        while True:
            line = (yield)
            f.write(line)
    return
```

Note you only need one `line = (yield)` instead of two.

Also, instead of priming the generator with `generator.send(None)` you could use the `coroutine` decorator:

```
def coroutine(func):
    """ http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/ """
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        gen = func(*args, **kw)
        gen.send(None)
        return gen
    return wrapper
```

This is a commonly understood idiom ([PEP0342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/), [David Beazley talk](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html)) for turning a generator into a coroutine. So decorating your generator with it would also serve the purpose of advertising that `write` is a coroutine.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to do generator.close() ?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: Yes, that would work too, but then is that really "Pythonic"? There does not seem be any benefit over `f=open(...); f.write(...); f.close()`.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack: f = stack.enter_context(open(...)) for execution of clean up code ? I use contextlib, because I need to open multiple files. It would be very elegant, if I could just open each file inside a generator.

Comment: I just saw your edit. I didn't know, I could just do "with f, g1, g2". It still gets ugly though, if I have to open hundreds of files.

Comment: I like the creativity of your solution, but my subjective opinion would be that using `contextlib.ExitStack()` will look cleaner, be more readable, than using the generator since each generator would need to be primed with `generator.send(None)` and explicitly closed.

Comment: Thank you unutbu. I will revert back to contextlib. I will accept this thread as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is somewhat subjective, but I believe "Pythonic" also means keeping it simple. And for your particular case, that would probably something along the lines of

```
open("blah.txt", 'w').write("""\
#You have been defeated!
#It's merely a flesh wound!
We are the knights who say Ni!
We are the knights who say Ni!
We are the knights who say Ni!
""")
```

I guess your *actual* case is different though...

Answer (score 0):

You're code is no shorter, and is no clearer, than

```
file='holygrail.txt'
header="#You have been defeated!\n#It's merely a flesh wound!\n"
with open(file, w) as fh:
    fh.write(header)
    for i in range(3):
        fh.write('We are the knights who say Ni!\n')
```

so I'm not sure what the benefit is.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the real input is coming from elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the real input is coming from elsewhere. The header from one file, which can easily be kept in memory and the data/body from multiple other files, which are all too large to be held in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The point of coroutines is in saving internal state between .send() calls.

Coroutines are often used to implement "consumer" pattern (I'm seldom using them to wrap xlwt worksheets: I need to track number of rows to flush them). Without any state you can use a simple function without any state (or .write() method of file object)